# How to access a ALSA audio device in android? How are they named?

Tags: android, audio, porting, alsa

1.How does android decide which component of a audio device acts as a microphone.Say the default ALSA device hw:0,0 has Line,CD,Mic1 and Mic2 as input, then which is used when we try to access the microphone's input from a app. Or does it use whatever is set as the input channel during startup with something like "alsa_amixer set line cap" in the init.rc. Which configuration files decides what is what?Which acts as Earpice,Headphone,Speaker etc. I went through the "asound.conf" file.There are no "asound.state" and "asound.names" files in the filesystem?

2.How do i declare a device (when say the device is named as "XYZ" in the "asound.conf" file) to be the source for the Voice Call Uplink and Downlink audio ? I know i can't do that from a app, but I just want to know how android does it?

I'm new to android.Hence this silly question.

Comment: There are no silly ALSA questions. ALSA is full of traps and poorly documented.